# Get Data from External File with jQuery Ajax Method

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to load the contents of an external file into a DIV:
[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/MonicaPonciano/nP8Ed/1/)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: fileName,
    dataType: "text"
}).done(function (data) {
    $("#test").text(data);
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("AJAX call failed: " + textStatus + ", " + errorThrown + ", "+ jqXHR);
});
```

But I get a "**Invalid argument**" error returned.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction here?

Comment: `alert(fileName);` would have shown you problem number 1.  Problem number 2 is that you can't open local files this way.

Comment: Have a look at the html5 filereader API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: If I am not wrong than you are trying to get content of the uploaded file than I guess you must upload your file at some destination and than you will be able to get content of it